# setMessageDrivenContext is not invoked

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss5.x

I am using EJB 2.0 **without annotation**. I have a ejb-jar.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC 
          "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN"
          "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">

<ejb-jar>
<enterprise-beans>

<message-driven>
        <ejb-name>XMLEventQueueBean00</ejb-name>
    <ejb-class>com.test.XMLEventRequestService</ejb-class>
    <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
    <acknowledge-mode>AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</acknowledge-mode>
    <message-driven-destination>
      <destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</destination-type>
    </message-driven-destination>

</message-driven>

</enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

And I have a bean

```
public class XMLEventRequestService implements MessageDrivenBean, MessageListener {
    private MessageDrivenContext    m_context;
    public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext ctx) {
        logger.debug("setMessageDrivenContext called");
        m_context = ctx;
    }

    public void ejbCreate() {
        logger.debug("ejbCreate called");
    }
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {

    }

}
```

But neither of the log is given and `m_context` gives NullPointerException when I called upon:

```
m_context.setRollbackOnly();
```

How can I set the context and why is it not invoke? (No annotation please. My supervisor prefers XML descriptor injection)

I am using JBoss 5.1.0.GA.

Comment: To make this clear, are you saying you are seeing the onMessage() method being invoked when you add a message to the queue, but the ejbCreate() and setMessageDrivenContext() methods are not invoked when the bean is first instantiated? 
Can you see that your MDB is deployed correctly (using the JBoss 5 console - JBossAS Servers->JBoss_EAP_5->Applications->Embedded_EJB2_JARs->(your jar)->XMLEventQueueBean00 
This will also show your current pool size and the number of messages processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EJB configuration was correct. I simply forgot to turn on the debug for the package.

Answer (score 0):

@texasbruce, it clearly shows your MDM is not deployed properly...one thing I notice you are not using JCA configuration, any specific reason or something you might not aware of....JCA is J2ee standard mechanism of configuring resources....You can deploy MDB in either non-JCA or JCA way, please read the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/mdb21imp001.htm#BABGFAFG)

Try following if you are using JBOSS5:

**ejb-jar.xml:**

```
<message-driven>
    <ejb-name>XMLEventQueueBean00</ejb-name>
    <ejb-class>com.test.XMLEventRequestService</ejb-class>
     <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
     <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
   <activation-config>
      <activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
        <activation-config-property-value>AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</activation-config-property-value>
      </activation-config-property>
    </activation-config>

</message-driven>
```

**jboss.xml**

```
<message-driven>
   <ejb-name>XMLEventQueueBean00</ejb-name>
   <destination-jndi-name>queue/YOUR-QUEUE-NAME</destination-jndi-name>
</message-driven>
```